# Hardware acceleration Used by Web Browser and it's testing

Tags: canvas, browser, automation, html5-canvas, hardware-acceleration

I never worked with browser before. Could you please share the details of how web browser use hardware acceleration?

Also, I'm developing an automated testing infrastructure for the same. What use cases/test cases I can cover in testing? Which scripts/tools would be helpful in building automation framework for browser testing?

Comment: The Graphics Processing Unit (gpu) is responsible for hardware acceleration. The gpu accelerates most rendering in html5 canvas except the pixel manipulation methods (f.ex .getImageData). The gpu uses 2 methods to accelerate rendering. First, it has built-in circuits specializing in the mathematics and other requirements of rendering. Second, it "remembers" what it previously rendered by keeping the rendered drawings in "frames". If the previous rendering hasn't changed, this lets the gpu quickly redraw the content without having to also re-render it. There's more, but that's the quick tour.

Comment: @markE: thanks! mark for the beautiful explanation. So call goes through OS runtime to driver. Does it use Direct2D on Windows? Or Direct3D? It would be helpful if you share the pipeline diagram between HTML/JavaScript and OS runtime.

Comment: You can certainly unit test most use-cases in your app. Tip: integrate your unit tests early.

Comment: Almost all rendering and drawing requirements are handed off to the gpu (if a gpu is available). That includes DirectX. You don't need to handle the pipeline because the cpu and gpu are extremely well integrated when cooperating to render and draw. Even the exceptions often involve the gpu. F.ex, when you use pixel manipulation on html canvas, the cpu uses its imageData array to modify pixels, but then the cpu pushes the ImageData to the gpu for processing. The browser will automatically use the gpu when the gpu is the best tool for the task

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks!